# Inserting into table using values from another table involving a unique filed

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The field which is giving me problems is a `unique` `required` field called `ItemNo` on `tbl1`. I want to copy the `ItemNo` field value from the `tbl2` and add it onto `tbl1` `ItemNo` filed but add `D` at the end of the string. All the `ItemNo` fields are formatted as `Text`

`tbl1` currently looks like:

```
ID   ItemNo   ItemDescription   ....
1    001      Epoxy resin       ....
2    002      Wood glue         ....
```

`tbl2` currently looks like:

```
ID   ItemNo   ItemDescription   ....
1    001      Epoxy resin       ....
2    002      WD40              ....
```

Expects `tb1` after update to look like:

```
ID   ItemNo   ItemDescription   ....
1    001      Epoxy resin       ....
2    002      Wood glue         ....
3    001D     Epoxy resin       ....
4    002D     WD40              ....
```

Perhaps something like:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM tbl2 ...."
```

I can accomplish the task using `DAO` with the following but wanted to know if its also possible using SQL.

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT*FROM tbl1")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT*FROM tbl2")

With rs2
.MoveFirst
Do Until rs2.EOF
rs1.AddNew
rs1.Fields("ItemNo").Value = rs2.Fields("ItemNo").Value & "D"
....
....
rs1.Edit
rs1.Update
rs2.MoveNext
Loop
End With
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
rs2.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Rather than having to list all of the fields to be copied in the DAO example, after setting the first field, you could have used a loop for the other fields (something like `For lngLoop1=1 to rs1.Fields.Count-1:rs1.Fields(lngLoop1)=rs2.Fields(lngLoop1):Next lngLoop1`)

Comment: @Applecore this does works but is slow for lots of records. The SQL statement seems faster but it looks like I will have to explicitly define all the fields in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want:

```
insert into tbl1 (itemNo, itemDescription)
    select itemNo & 'd', itemDescription
    from tbl2;
```

This assumes that `id` is automatically assigned.

Comment: @Godon Linoff thanks! Do I need to specify all the other 28 remaining fields to the statement?

Comment: @Fil . . . If you want to insert them, then yes.

Comment: thanks. I thought I could get away with having to add all the other Columns to the statement but  it looks like I actually have to. Thanks works fine!